# set uniqueidentifier in java callablestatement

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, uniqueidentifier, callable-statement

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure like follows:

```
CallableStatement cs = this.con.prepareCall("{call getDeliveryConfirmations(?)}");
cs.setString(1, "545A6F33-A22A-47A6-AF97-0D952F2D80D7");
Resultset rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

As you can see I'm setting a Guid/UniqueIdentifier in the callable statement as a parameter before executing... But as you also can make out is that I use the method 'setString' on the callableStatement object and as a result I'm getting this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

I'd imagine that if there was a method like 'setGuid' or something for the callablestatement object that I won't have this problem... Anyone know of a workaround etc?

**Edit:**

Code for the stored procedure 'getDeliveryConfirmations'

```
USE [VodacomXml2Sms]
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select * from OutgoingDeliveryConfirmations
where smsGuid = @selectedGuid
END
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `getDeliveryConfirmations` as well (at least the declaration)?

Comment: There you go... Obviously @selectedGuid is the parameter I'm sending through to the stored proc in the java code

Answer (score 0):

I fear if your Guid and uniqueidentifier have data type or size mismatch.
Check if [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1476916) works for you.

Comment: What happens when you declare a variable meant for a guid like this: declare (at)guidParameter varchar; instead of declare (at)guidParameter nvarchar(36); ? Could this potentially be the reason for the error?

Comment: @DeanGrobler - I am not sure about that, but can you please check your call with `cs.setNString(..)`