# SSIS Convert string to a guid when importing and saving data

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012, ssis, data-conversion

I was trying to convert a unicode string from an Excel File into a uniqueidentifier. There are already answers online that seem pretty straight forward:

I've seen this post: [Data Conversion Issue in SSIS package - Text to GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356198/data-conversion-issue-in-ssis-package-text-to-guid/18876226#18876226)

and this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6ce5b4d2-913a-40f1-9797-105783181f5e/ssis-variable-that-should-contain-uniqueidentifier

But this didn't work in SSIS 2012 in Visual Studio 2012 when importing data to SQL Server 2012, I would get the typical conversion error when running it.

In the Excel File the Guid (as a string) was stored in this format:

> 00bce79b-6c7b-427f-9711-17c19475f6e4

No curly braces or quotes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To get this to work, still type in the derived column expression as:

```
(DT_GUID)("{" + [ColumnName] + "}")
```

But you need to configure the error output and change the columns where you are doing this conversion to `Ignore Failure` instead of `Fail Component`.

If you do this and run it, it WILL work and properly convert and import despite what the debugger tells you.

Comment: For me, it worked without needing to ignore any errors.

Comment: Thank you, this saved me.