# SSIS conversion from string to GUID

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package variable `SomeId` of type `string`(as there isn't an option in SSIS package variable pane for setting it to a GUID).

In the 'Derived Column' step I have set the variable's Expression as `(DT_GUID)@[User::SomeId]` and DataType auto sets to `unique identifier [DT_GUID]`

Next step is the 'OLE Db Destination'

I have 'enabled Data Viewer' between the above two steps and I can see the `SomeId` column with a new guid populated. However as soon as it tries to import it to a database table it fails with below error.

> [NameOfOleDbDest1[181]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast
>   specification".

I'm thinking it has something to do with how I'm casting the variable to DT_GUID, however the other ways* mentioned by people on stackoverlfow raises error on the expression with red highlight.

*Here are other ways I've tried to cast string to guid but error is raised:

```
(DT_GUID)[User::SomeId]
(DT_GUID)("{" + [User::SomeId] + "}")
```

only when I try `(DT_GUID)@[User::SomeId]` does it succeed. But obviously the above error is raised when I execute the package.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18876226/73226

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it works. But I don't really like that approach, there has to be a proper way to convert a string to a guid.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same solution as the referenced answer, but hopefully adding it here clarifies it a bit.

I resolved this issue by wrapping the variable in curly braces using the following expression.

```
"{" + @[User::string_id] + "}"
```

The variable type in the derived column remained DT_WSTR but the value was converted correctly when inserted into the destination table.

This also helps to resolve the issue of using a string value GUID as a parameter on an OLEDB SOURCE. For that, I create a 2nd variable and use the expression builder to reference the 1st variable and wrap it in curly braces using the same expression. I then use the 2nd variable as my input parameter in the source query.