# SSIS handle GUID strings without "-" character

Tags: ssis, guid

I am loading data from a CSV to SQL table. CSV file has two GUID columns one with "-" and one without "-"

Column 1 values like "D59695EF-626D-479C-B73E-FD047577B743"

Column 2 has values like "D59695EF626D479CB73EFD047577B743"

I could load the column 1 values using derived transformation to Database but struggling with column 2 values.

For loading Column 1 values i have done similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356198/data-conversion-issue-in-ssis-package-text-to-guid).

Could someone help me here?

Comment: Have you tried stuffing the dashes in the right place using string functions then converting? Whats the error you currently get? What datatypes are the source columns? `DT_WSTR`?

Comment: For now i am getting type conversion error. and my source data type is string.
I have not tried stuffing dashes. Will try that