# Create custom defined unique identifier

Tags: sql, guid

I have a table with uniqueidentifier column. Insert script looks like this :

```
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserId], [Name], [Surname]) VALUES (NEWID(), 'SomeName', 'SomeSurname')
```

NEWID() creates new GUID, which is inserted to table. I would like to create some data with defined id column, not automatically generated. E.g. 'a0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'. This code doesn't work because it throws error 'String or binary data would be truncated.' :

```
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserId], [Name], [Surname]) VALUES ('a0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 'SomeName', 'SomeSurname')
```

I tried cast this custom guid, but I was not successful as well.

```
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserId], [Name], [Surname]) VALUES (CAST('a0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS uniqueidentifier), 'SomeName', 'SomeSurname')
```

Do you have any clue how I can solve inserting data with custom defined ID?

Comment: have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390109/convert-varchar-to-uniqueidentifier-in-sql-server ?

Comment: Are you sure the field userid is a unqiueidentifier field, your example "guid" inserts just fine into a unqiueidentifier field.

Comment: @Jester yes, of course

Comment: @BenRobinson You're right. This error was caused by another column

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to cast it. SQL Server will do it for you.

This code works well:

```
create table x
( a uniqueidentifier
);

insert into x values ('A0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
;

insert into x values ('BBE46A77-3518-40E4-9B77-3275F3531B8B')
;

select *
from x
;
```