# String to a GUID via inline C# within ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, guid

Is it possible to use convert a string to a GUID via inline C# within ASP.NET? In this example I would like to pass in a string for `CustomerId` and have it formatted as a GUID as the stored procedure expects a Unique Identifier.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="myDataSOurce" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="GetUserData" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<% new Guid(customerId).ToString() %>" Name="CustomerId" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I try this I get an error from SQL Server:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Sure, you can convert a string to a Guid in C#. Your error seems  to be a type problem. I suspect declaring your parameter type as a string here is confusing it.

Comment: Tried just using `new Guid(customerId)` initially but received the same error. Could the `new` keyword be the issue?

Comment: Maybe use a Binding Expression `DefaultValue='<%# new Guid(customerId).ToString() %>'` But why convert to a Guid and then call ToString on it, then it becomes `customerId` again basically.

Comment: I figured `.ToString()` would give me a string with the formatting present in a GUID (i.e. dashes). I also tried the binding syntax and it is rejected because the control doesn't  implement `DataBind`

Comment: I think you want to use `Type="Object"` for a guid. (not confirmed)

Comment: If I hard code the GUID (i.e. 'XXXXX-YYYYYY-ZZZZZZZ-AAAAAAA') it works without issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to modify your stored procedure to accept string and then cast the string to uniqueidentifier in your SQL code. If yes, check this
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390129/6742887)

There are a couple of comments on that answer that achieve the same thing with less code.
However, if that is not possible, see if this works.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="myDataSOurce" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="GetUserData" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<% System.Guid.Parse(customerId) %>" Name="CustomerId" DbType="Guid" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<% Guid.NewGuid() %>" Name="CustomerId" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Same error. For some reason SQL is not accepting it as a Unique Identifier