How to convert C#’s Guid constructor with array of bytes to SQL Server scalar function?
I am currently tasked with converting a bunch of C# CLR code into SQL Server stored procedures and scalar functions. The task seems enough simple at first glance, until I stumbled upon a piece of code that generates a new Guid with a byte array as parameter.
The code looks like this:
public static Guid GenerateGuid()
{
     var bytes = GenerateBytes();
     return new Guid(bytes);
}

The bytes generated is not the concern here, what puzzles me is how C# uses this byte array to create a new Guid instance. In SQL Server, however, there is only one function NEWID() which accepts no parameter, it is similar to Guid.NewGuid().
Unfortunately it is not what I need for this use case.
So I'd like to ask there a way I can rewrite the above C# code into T-SQL to generate a new guid with specified byte array instead of just a completely random guid using NEWID()?

Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390129/4503491 is useful?

The above link seems to be about presentation formatting of uniqueidentifiers. Be aware that the binary serilaization of uniqueidentifiers is probably not quite as you expect, e.g.: declare @foo uniqueidentifier = 'a89b1acd-9501-6ae6-b9c8-aabb07da2010'; select @foo, cast(@foo as varbinary(max));

The proper conversion of a byte array (BINARY(16) in SQL) to a Guid (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) depends on whether your byte array is arranged with the first three parts (one 4-byte integer and two 2-byte integers) in a little-endian host byte order or in a big-endian network byte order. If you need to maintain compatibility and consistency across platforms, you need to know which form your data is in to select the proper conversion.
If the bytes are already arranged in host byte order, as appears to be the case for C# Guid.ToByteArray() results, the SQL Server conversion is simply:
DECLARE @HostOrderBytes BINARY(16) = 0x33221100554477668899aabbccddeeff
DECLARE @Result UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @HostOrderBytes)
SELECT @Result -- 00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff

However, if the byte array is in network byte order, the conversion requires some rearrangement of the data before conversion. Specifically, bytes 1 through 4, 5 & 6, and 7 & 8 each need to be reversed to place the data in host order.
The following will accomplish this:
DECLARE @NetworkOrderBytes BINARY(16) = 0x00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff

DECLARE @HostOrderBytes BINARY(16) =
    SUBSTRING(@NetworkOrderBytes,4,1)   -- Reverse bytes 1-4 (0-3)
    + SUBSTRING(@NetworkOrderBytes,3,1)
    + SUBSTRING(@NetworkOrderBytes,2,1)
    + SUBSTRING(@NetworkOrderBytes,1,1)
    + SUBSTRING(@NetworkOrderBytes,6,1) -- Reverse bytes 5-6 (4-5)
    + SUBSTRING(@NetworkOrderBytes,5,1)
    + SUBSTRING(@NetworkOrderBytes,8,1) -- Reverse bytes 7-8 (6-7)
    + SUBSTRING(@NetworkOrderBytes,7,1)
    + SUBSTRING(@NetworkOrderBytes,9,8) -- Remaining bytes are unchanged

DECLARE @Result UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @HostOrderBytes)

SELECT @Result -- 00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff

An alternative is to convert the bytes to a hex string, inject the appropriate dashes, and then convert to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. The last step of this approach handles the byte order issues.
DECLARE @NetworkOrderBytes BINARY(16) = 0x00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff

DECLARE @Result UNIQUEIDENTIFIER =
    CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
       STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @NetworkOrderBytes, 2),
           9 , 0, '-'), 14, 0, '-'), 19, 0, '-'), 24, 0, '-'))

SELECT @Result -- 00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff

See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
For a related discussion about byte order see SQL Server GUID sort algorithm. Why?.

@Charlieface - Good catch. I have updated my answer. (My prior experience with this was implementing an RFC 4122 version 5 SHA-1 name-based UUID, which required byte swapping to get the correct answer, per RFC sample data. It didn't occur to me that the C# byte array might already be in host byte order.)
